# Removing 1. commit before pushing

Tags: git

I have made an accidentally changes in core files and saved it and made a commit. and make another changes and created new commit. and my real project is in commit 1.

```
commit e8e7a9.... 
Author: 
Date: 

         Commit message 1 (Real Project)
 ----------------------------------------------
commit e8e7a9.... 
Author: 
Date: 

         Commit message 2 (Remove this one)
 ----------------------------------------------
commit e8e7a9.... 
Author: 
Date: 

         Commit message 3 ( It must be there)
```

I only want to delete commit, but If I do it, am I going to update the removed commit or how danger is it and how can I do it?

is it correct if I use ?

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2
```

UPDATE:

After I must push to remote git server a new branch with the 2.Commit only if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok to use

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2
```

This will unstage your changes in last two commits, which does not mean you have lost your changes. After this you can use

```
git status
```

to view all the changes. You can remove the ones which are not required and then commit the required ones.

```
git add <the_required_files>
git commit -m "my commit message"
```

You can push afterwards just like you did

```
git push <remote_name> <branch_name>
```

Comment: can I return back to commit 3 without losing any changes?

Comment: you will not lose your changes if you do a soft reset. If you are skeptical (which everyone would be since this is version control and no one wants to lose their changes), switching to a test branch before doing soft reset is an option.

Soft reset HEAD^2 would unstage your commits #2 and #3. Remove the unwanted changes, do a commit, push it.

Answer (score 0):

`git reset --soft` can be used (as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39143568/4265352)), `git reset --mixed` is even better, but there are other, easier, ways.

#### Solution #1

For example, you can create a temporary branch or a tag on commit #3, just to have a reference to it, reset hard your current branch to commit #1, cherry-pick commit #3 and, if you're satisfied with the result, remove the temporary branch or tag:

```
# assuming the current branch points to commit #3
git branch temp
git reset --hard HEAD~2
git cherry-pick temp
git branch -d temp
```

#### Solution #2

Another solution is to use [`git rebase --interactive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

```
git rebase --interactive HEAD~2
```

It opens in your editor a file that contains 2 lines (and usage directions in a comment below them). The lines describe your last two commits. Remove the first one (after you make sure it displays the same hash as commit #2), save the file and quit the editor. `Git` processes the file and, in background, it does operations similar to those presented in solution #1 above.